# CSV File not uploading through php and jquery(ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to upload a csv file using this code but the file directory is not getting uploaded to the folder and i cannot see any error in the code.
Please help me in this.

HTML code:

`<form method="POST" action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="upload"><br>
</form>`

JQUERY AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#upload').on('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var file=this.files[0];
        console.log(file);    
        var filename = file.name;
        var ext = filename.split('.')[1];
        if(ext == "csv"){
            FileUploadAjaxCall();
        }else{

            $("#fileMsg").html("Extension not valid:Try Again");
        }                     
    });
});

function FileUploadAjaxCall(){  
    $.ajax({
            url:'submit.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:new FormData($('#upload').get(0)),
            contentType:false,
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data){
                if(data == 1){
                    console.log("File Uploaded Successfully");
                }else{
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            }
        });
}`
```

PHP code:

```
<?php    

        $file = $_FILES['file'];

        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $filetmpname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $fileDes = 'uploads/'.$filename;
            $t = move_uploaded_file($filetmpname,$fileDes);
            if($t == true){
                echo 1;
            };

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-written your code as follows. Its always good to validate files upload at server backend and javascript validation can be fooled.

Try the code below and let me see what happens

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload_processor.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
            $("#targetLayer").html(data);
                        $("#errorLayer").html(data);
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form id="uploadForm" action="upload_processor.php" method="post">
<div id="targetLayer"></div>

<div id="errorLayer"></div>

<div id="uploadFormLayer">
<input name="file" type="file" class="inputFile" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>




<?php
if(is_array($_FILES)) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {

$fileName   = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];

if($fileName ==''){
echo "<div id='errorLayer'>Please select file</div>";
exit;
}

$fileType = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $allowTypes = array('csv');
            if (!in_array($fileType, $allowTypes, true)) {
               echo "<div id='errorLayer'>File type is invalid. Only CSV is allowed</div>";
exit;
            }


if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
echo "<div id='targetLayer'>File  uploaded successfully</div>";
?>

<?php
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: it worked thanx but what changes have you done.?  @nancy

Answer (score 0):

//form.html

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php" id="uploadForm">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="upload" accept=".csv"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="fileMsg"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(e){
   $('#uploadForm').on('submit', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'submit.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:new FormData(this),
            contentType:false,
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(){
                    $("#fileMsg").html("File Uploaded Successfully");
                },
            error:function(){
                    //$("#fileMsg").html(data);
                    $("#fileMsg").html("Error");
                }

        });
     });
   });

 </script>
```

//submit.php

```
<?php

  //  $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filetmpname = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $fileDes = "uploads/".$filename;
        $t = move_uploaded_file($filetmpname,$fileDes);
        if($t == true){
            echo "1";
        };

  ?>
```

u can do it like this